# Can't add javascript to divi footer in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, divi

I am using the divi theme and had a simple line of javascript running in footer.php:

```
<script>
    console.log("inside of footer.php");
</script>
```

Then, i used Divi Theme Builder to make a custom footer and found that footer.php was no longer running. I need to add javascript back into the footer but can't figure out what file to enter it in. How do I place javascript into the footer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief tutorial by the creators of Divi covering how to include javascript on your Divi website.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/best-practices-for-using-external-javascript-snippets-with-divi

Assuming you want to include your code in the footer for UX/SEO reasons, then the best route is probably to go to **Divi > Theme Options > Integration** and paste your code in the **Add code to the `<body>`** section.

This will insert your code immediately before the closing `</body>` tag on all your pages.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended at all to edit the footer.php template in an external theme.

The way we use this is.

1. Go to `your_page/wp-content/themes/active_theme_name`
2. Create a custom.js
3. Then in the functions.php add this line:

`wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);`

Read, now you can write your `console.log("inside of footer.php");` in a custom.js file.